# Generate texture UIImage from small image in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, textures

I want to create a full size texture image lets say 1000 x 1000 from existing `UIImage` of size 40 x 40.

The code I am using to create the image is

```
let textureImg = UIImage(CGImage: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(textureImage?.CGImage, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)))!)
```

where `textureImage` is some image in 40x40.

Please let me know any correct method to achieve this as the code above not giving proper result. The whole image comes white.

Comment: By texture, do you mean "tiled"? If so, check out CIAffineTile (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineTile). If you need some code for it, let me know.

Comment: `let textureImg = UIImage(color: UIColor(patternImage: textureImage!), size: CGSizeMake(300, 300))!` works fine to generate tiled image same as `CIAffineTile`. However, I was not able to properly implement CIAffineTile, example would be great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to use CIAffineTile to tile a 40x40 image into a 500x500 one. Be aware, I'm doing some unneeded forced unwrapping, etc. because I pulled this from existing code. This is tested.

```
let inputImage = UIImage(named: "vermont.jpg")
let tiledImage = createTiledImage(inputImage:inputImage!)
print(inputImage!.size)  // displays (40.0, 40.0)
print(tiledImage.size)   // displays (500.0,500.0)
imageView.image = tiledImage

func createTiledImage(inputImage:UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTile")
    filter!.setValue(CIImage(image: inputImage), forKey: "inputImage")
    let outputImage = filter?.outputImage?.applyingFilter("CIAffineTile", withInputParameters: nil).cropping(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
    let ciCtx = CIContext(options: nil)
    let cgimg = ciCtx.createCGImage(outputImage!, from: (outputImage?.extent)!)
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
}
```

Comment: Any reason that you are using CIAffineTile twice, instead of "filter" simply being the original image?

Comment: Probably not? As noted, I pulled this from existing code and tested. From what I see you should be able to either (a) add the `inputImage` into the `let outputImage =` statement or (b) change the outputImage call to simply be `filter?outputImage` - remembering there's a ton of forced unwraps, etc., you can get rid of. (Yes, it's sloppy code - as in *not* production ready - but it does answer the question.)